# How is this Pmin() function working indexing a column?

Tags: r

I struggled to find a good title for this post, so apologies if this isn't the best to describe what I am asking here. Let's say I have a data frame with 50 columns, and I want to split it up by 2 columns, resulting in a list of 25 data frames.

```
col_one  col_two  col_three  col_four  col_five ... col_fifty
1          1          1          1         1            1
2          2          2          2         2            2
```

One way I've been able to solve this is through map function and the pmin() function as such:

```
purrr::map(seq(1, ncol(data), by = 2), ~ data[.x:pmin((.x + 1), ncol(data))])
```

However, the more I thought about this, the more I thought that I could simply drop the pmin() function and do the same task like this:

```
purrr::map(seq(1, ncol(data), by = 2), ~ data[, .x:.x+1])
```

This does create list of 25 data.frames, but it only prints out one column rather than two columns.

Could anybody explain why? Thanks!

Comment: I think you should add brackets around the `.x+1` such as `data[, .x:(.x+1)]`. Currently you are taking the range from `.x` to `.x` and adding `1` to it. As for the `pmin`: it makes sure that you do not select any column index that is higher than the total number of columns, which would throw an error.

Comment: Compare `1:2 + 1` and `1:(2 + 1)`

Comment: Yikes, do I feel dumb. :P Thanks for the help to both of you!